# Is the word 懵逼 dirty?

Tags: swearing

懵逼 is easily construed as dirty with it's 逼 suffix. I cannot, for certain, tell if 逼 is a substitute for 屄 or not.

[Baidu Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%87%B5%E9%80%BC/19673061?fr=aladdin) gives no indication that it's a curse word.

But [懵X](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E6%87%B5X&rsv_spt=1&rsv_iqid=0x9960830800023d36&issp=1&f=8&rsv_bp=0&rsv_idx=2&ie=utf-8&tn=baiduhome_pg&rsv_enter=1&rsv_sug3=1&rsv_sug2=0&inputT=187&rsv_sug4=188) brings up almost four million results on Baidu & 懵屄 has it's own fair-share of results.

Could it just be a happy coincidence?

Comment: No, it is not a curse word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not polite or appropriate, but has been used so much by teenagers on the internet that it has become quite acceptable on social media. Middle-aged people will consider it a very bad word to say.

A more appropriate substitution for it could be "懵圈". However, both words should never be used in an official context.

And yes, 逼 is a substitute for 屄 and is more commonly used.(Both characters I've rarely used before answering the question...)

Answer (score 1):

It's dirty, no doubt, the original one is 懵, just 懵, adding 逼 suffix is like 'confussied', no matter how popular it is on internet, it is still a dirty word.

Comment: More like "confused af" and equally dirty/not dirty.